# Jupyter Notebook Kernel dying on specific enviorment

Tags: windows, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nvidia

I recently reinstall my Anaconda, and then I created a new Conda environment with the name `myenv`.
Then I installed necessary packages in it such as Jupyter, Numpy, Pandas, Tensorflow 2, Keras etc.

Now when I opened Jupyter notebook, It was working. When I clicked on a New Notebook> Python 3 : (myenv),
It gave me a very big error, and kernel is dying.

I believe that the error is somehow related to my NVIDIA drivers, but it was working perfectly fine before.

Also, It is detecting GPU when I

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
```

Then after a long output, it gives

```
GPU:0 with 1380 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce MX110, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
2020-07-20 22:32:54.350989: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x20284f8ac10 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-07-20 22:32:54.355860: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce MX110, Compute Capability 5.0
Out[2]: True
```

Which means GPU is working.

The Error I get in Jupyter Notebook is

```
[W 22:33:54.958 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20200720222753 (::1) 10.00ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/Untitled1.ipynb
[E 22:33:56.401 NotebookApp] Failed to run command:
    ['C:\\Anaconda\\envs\\myenv\\python.exe', '-m', 'ipykernel_launcher', '-f', 'C:\\Users\\Ahmad Mustafa Anis\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-d6e4e2e3-6570-48ac-808e-8a456b430033.json']
        PATH='C:\\Anaconda\\envs\\myenv;C:\\Anaconda\\envs\\myenv\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin;C:\\Anaconda\\envs\\myenv\\Library\\usr\\bin;C:\\Anaconda\\envs\\myenv\\Library\\bin;C:\\Anaconda\\envs\\myenv\\Scripts;C:\\Anaconda\\envs\\myenv\\bin;C:\\Anaconda\\condabin;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v10.1\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v10.1\\libnvvp;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0;C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\Nsight Compute 2019.1;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Anaconda;C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin;C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\usr\\bin;C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin;C:\\Anaconda\\Scripts;C:\\Users\\Ahmad Mustafa Anis\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\Ahmad Mustafa Anis\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v10.1\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v10.1\\libnvvp;C:\\Users\\Ahmad Mustafa Anis\\Downloads\\cmder;.;C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Professional Edition with Anaconda plugin 2020.1.2\\bin;.'
        with kwargs:
    {'stdin': -1, 'stdout': None, 'stderr': None, 'cwd': 'C:\\Users\\Ahmad Mustafa Anis\\Desktop', 'close_fds': False}

[E 22:34:20.721 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception POST /api/sessions (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='POST', uri='/api/sessions', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1703, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
        yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
        type=mtype))
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
        yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
        kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
        yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
        self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
        yielded = next(result)
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
        super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 186, in start_kernel
        km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 308, in start_kernel
        self.kernel = self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 215, in _launch_kernel
        return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 135, in launch_kernel
        proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "c:\users\ahmad mustafa anis\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[W 22:34:20.727 NotebookApp] Unhandled error
[E 22:34:20.728 NotebookApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Content-Length": "149",
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "X-Xsrftoken": "2|75d26d1d|23d90b6fbf2e9d8bd4e7f57882dbc1c6|1593362714",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Origin": "http://localhost:8888",
      "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
      "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
      "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/Untitled2.ipynb?kernel_name=python37764bitmyenvconda4a11ba26287d4d1c969b9946e31eb2a2",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,ur;q=0.8",
      "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|75d26d1d|23d90b6fbf2e9d8bd4e7f57882dbc1c6|1593362714; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1595266075|23:username-localhost-8888|44:MjhjNzFlOWEyM2M4NDFjMzlkYWY4Mzc5YzRkMGFjNDc=|cd2a2851f9a9f34c991b1b89b72f8378035cc40aa421b0489e390366ed50e85b\""
    }
[E 22:34:20.728 NotebookApp] 500 POST /api/sessions (::1) 24336.38ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/Untitled2.ipynb?kernel_name=python37764bitmyenvconda4a11ba26287d4d1c969b9946e31eb2a2
[W 22:34:20.737 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20200720222753 (::1) 6.00ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/Untitled2.ipynb?kernel_name=python37764bitmyenvconda4a11ba26287d4d1c969b9946e31eb2a2
[I 22:34:22.257 NotebookApp] Interrupted...
[I 22:34:22.258 NotebookApp] Shutting down 1 kernel
[I 22:34:22.558 NotebookApp] Kernel shutdown: 40dadb8b-1219-4bf9-a735-242f99f0b5b4
```

It mentions the `path` so Here is my environment Path picture.
[image: Path]

I regret deleting the old working Anaconda now. Please Help me Fix the Problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Running Ubuntu and also had the uphappy moments as I reinstalled everything and could not get tensorflow using my dual GPU's.

I tried 10,000 ways to install Ubuntu, Anaconda, etc.

What worked - install ubuntu.  Install anaconda.

conda install tensorflow-gpu

If I do it this way the conda install gets all the nvidia heck stuff done right - correct cudnn, toolkit, driver, etc.  I had been using pip install and had mostly been trying to get drivers and all the nvidia stuff done before the tensorflow install.  Pip install was not getting the right matching nvidia stuff installed.